# Changing the style of login field in picture

Tags: css, margin

I would like to make the login and password field  in thesame order. when i try to change order in css file with margin command, it moves both field.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should re-phrase your question because it simply does not make any sense. Also post some markup/css instead of a screenshot so we can actually what you did. Create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us to play with.

Comment: Well, reading you question again, you talk about "order", you mean placing the above `input` below the below `input`? **kullanici adi** goes below the **sifre** ?

Comment: no what i tried to say is i want both field in one order. username field is right. password field is at left. i want them in one line. when i tried to move fields my margin-left: 10px; it moves both fields

Comment: That was my first impression from you question, damn, I deleted the comment! use css [float](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float) to fix that. If you had some code on your question a workable solution could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. There are many way to do it, but this is the most straighforward.

http://jsfiddle.net/QutGz/1/

dunno want is going on width the fiddle. You can accomplish evening out the "columns" like this:

```
label
{
float:left;
width: 100px;
}

input
{
float:left;
}
```

​
Set the width to something that will be larger than the largest label text.

Comment: Oh I figured it out. I know the html is wrong, but I didn't get any text rendered by declaring text="". I updated to the fiddle the shows working markup

Comment: two point to that: 1. quotes are optional (just to be nitpicky), and 2. I play my crappy markup on intellisense usually doing this stuff for me. :)

Comment: Why quotes round attributes should always be included -> http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/qattr.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS float](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float) to fix the inputs position in relation to each other and their parents elements:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Bvya2/) example!

**Assuming a structure like:**

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="clear">
    <label>KULLANICI ADI</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="foo">
  </div>
  <div class="clear">
    <label>SIFRE</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="bar">
  </div>
</form>
```

**The CSS solution would be:**

```
input[type="text"] {
  float: right;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
```